# what would be the code for connecting to event hubs from Azure Databricks Pyspark notebook that used Managed service Identity on Event hubs?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

What would be the connection string template for connecting to Event hubs from Databricks ( Pyspark) where MSI authentication is used from Databricks on Event hubs

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Databricks clusters doesn't have managed identity attached, so you won't be able to connect to EventHubs using this method. If you can't use EventHubs' Shared Access Policy, then the closest alternative would be to use Service Principal client ID/secret using [this code](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-playground/tree/main/kafka-eventhubs-aad-auth) that you can install as a library to your cluster.